# How to enable tomcat Host Manager storeconfig?

Tags: tomcat, virtual, host, persist

Tomcat Virtual Host Manager, Persist configuration;
Message:
FAIL - Failed to persist configuration
Please enable StoreConfig to use this feature.

Answer (score 3):

By default that functionality is disabled. So, you need to add this listener to enable it in server.xml file.

```
  <Server>
    <!-- Enable Persistence -->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>
    ...
```

You can see more information [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat85/docs/host-manager-howto.html#Persist_command).